# Dyanmically adding control into field form database on web form

Tags: asp.net, sql, dynamic, webforms

So the title is kind of confusing. I'll try and clear this up as much as possible.

I'm working with an open source shopping cart (nopCommerce). I've decided that I'm going to build this into a cart that I can spin up over and over again without having to change the code behind or the front-end code. I want everything to come from the database and the CSS files. So I need to make a database field that controls the header menu.

I want to dynamically add a string of HTML from the database onto the page. Easy enough. I've got that taken care of. The problem is: right in the middle of all this code, I need to add a user control. So what I've done is created a div (that is run at the server) in the HTML string.

I attach the HTML string in the Page_PreInit

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        headermenu.InnerHtml = GetLocaleResourceString("Header.InnerHTML");
    }
```

Then I try in the Page_Load to create the user control dynamically. Find the DIV from the InnerHTML of the headerMenu and insert it there.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        Control navControl = LoadControl("~/Modules/CategoryNavigationFooter.ascx");
        var divControl = this.Page.FindControl("divCategoryContainer");

        divControl.Controls.Add(navControl);
    }
```

Every time it looks for that control. It doesn't find it and returns null. Here's the code that's coming out of the database:

```
<ul class="topmenu sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow" id="nav-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="~/" runat="server" id="menuHomeLink">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="~/AboutUs.aspx" runat="server" id="menuAboutUsLink">About Us</a>
            <ul id="ourstory">
                <li><a href="~/Staff.aspx" runat="server" id="menuStaffLink">Meet the Staff</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="~/Blog.aspx" id="menuBlogLink" runat="server">Blog</a>
            <ul id="blog">
                <li><a href="~/Blog.aspx?tag=favorite-posts" id="menuBlogFavorite">Favorite Posts</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="~/Store.aspx" runat="server" id="menuStoreLink">Store</a>
        <div id="divCategoryContainer" runat="Server"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="~/Gallery.aspx" runat="server" id="menuGalleryLink">Gallery</a>
                <ul id="gallery">
                    <li><a href="~/Pictures.aspx" runat="server" id="menuPictures">Pictures</a></li>
                    <li><a href="~/Videos.aspx" runat="server" id="menuVideos">Videos</a></li>
                </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="~/NewsArchive.aspx" id="menuNewsLink" runat="server">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="~/ContactUs.aspx" id="menuContactLink" runat="server">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated guys. I've spent the last day on this and can't afford to waste any more time.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use dynamic control i suggest that you use a panel control and at page_init you can use the panle.controls.add(new litralcontrol("html"); to insert any div or asp control there. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do `FindControl` on html literal string. `FindControl` will only work on page control tree - `headerMenu` control will be there in the control tree. However any html that you set up as content to that control will not be part of control tree - that html will treated as string by the control and will be emitted into the page output (so your `runat="server"` will also be seen in the html output).

The solution would be to have some placeholder string into your html and then substitute that with actual div control. For example,

```
var html = GetLocaleResourceString("Header.InnerHTML");
// look for our placeholder
var parts = html.split(new string[] { "#MY_DIV_PLACEHOLDER#" });
headerMenu.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl() { Text = parts[0] });
headerMenu.Controls.Add(new Placeholder() { ID="divCategoryContainer" });
headerMenu.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl() { Text = parts[1] });
```